# How to fix "TypeError: data type not understood" in numpy when creating transformer no peak mask

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to implement and train a transformer for NMT via a blog post, everything works except I can't create the no peaking mask as I get this error: "TypeError: data type not understood"

Code:

```py
target_seq = batch.Python.transpose(0,1)
target_pad = PY_TEXT.vocab.stoi['<pad>']
target_msk = (target_seq != target_pad).unsqueeze(1)
size = target_seq.size(1) # get seq_len for matrix
nopeak_mask = np.triu(np.ones(1, size, size),
k=1).astype('uint8')
nopeak_mask = Variable(torch.from_numpy(nopeak_mask) == 0)
target_msk = target_msk & nopeak_mask
```

Error message:

```py
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-e19167b74ba0> in <module>()
      4 target_msk = (target_seq != target_pad).unsqueeze(1)
      5 size = target_seq.size(1) # get seq_len for matrix
----> 6 nopeak_mask = np.triu(np.ones(1, size, size),
      7 k=1).astype('uint8')
      8 nopeak_mask = Variable(torch.from_numpy(nopeak_mask) == 0)

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in ones(shape, dtype, order)
    201 
    202     """
--> 203     a = empty(shape, dtype, order)
    204     multiarray.copyto(a, 1, casting='unsafe')
    205     return a

TypeError: data type not understood
```

Comment: The first argument for `np.ones` should be a tuple of sizes: `np.ones((1,size,size))`.  The way you wrote it, `size` is interpreted as the dtype, the 2nd argument to `np.ones`.  Notice how the error points to the `np.empty` function call, with the same requirement - `shape, dtype, order`.

Comment: @hpaulj thank you, appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first input to `np.triu` should be a tuple of desired sizes instead of a numpy array.

Try:

```
np.triu((1, size, size), k=1).astype("uint8")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not giving a tuple while using np.ones() functionality

Try:

```
nopeak_mask = np.triu(np.ones((1, size, size)), k=1).astype("uint8")
```

It worked very well in my case, hope it would help in your case too
:)